# Multiple <head> and <body> tag

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a very simple web application, basically to understand the best practices of coding in HTML5, CSS and JavaScript.

My application has 3-4 pages and each one is using same menu header. So I want to make it reusable by writing it in a separate file (either PHP or HTML).

**head.php** (it is to be made reusable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../../css/headermenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="home">Home<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
<p> 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**front.php:**

```
<?php
    include ("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/page/common/head.php");
?>
```

**HTML markup** (dirty code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../../css/headermenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="home">Home<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
<p> 
</p>
</body>
</html></head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have following questions:

1. `head.php` has both `<body>` and `<head>` tag. So where should I write these PHP lines to include it? (in `<head>` or `<body>`)  (I don't want to have multiple `<head>`s and `<body>`s in the final page)
2. What are the other best practice I should follow? (any link to references welcome)

I have already read w3schools.

Comment: @AmalMurali +1:). Any reference/link for correcting my basics :)

Comment: @pc-shooter Don't downvote someone for very reasonably assuming the first result on Google is a good one. Blame Google/W3Schools instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right! Upvoted again thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it would be a good idea to read about templating systems or have a look how frameworks/CMS handle this.

Doing it your way, you can't completly avoid repeating e.g. the closing head tag `</head>` in every content.php.

**So this is just an idea:**

***head.php***

```
<?php
    // Some other includes / requires,
   // code snippets...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- site-wide stylesheets -->
        <!-- & js-files -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my/global/scripts.js"></script>
```

***content.php***

```
<?php
    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/page/common/head.php');
?>

    <!-- put page specific scripts &     
    <!-- styles here -->
    <link href="my/pages/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my/pages/js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- content start -->
        <div id="content">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <p>Your content</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end of content div -->
<?php
    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/page/common/foot.php');
```

***foot.php***

```
        <div id="foot">
               copyright etc
        </div> 
    </div> <!-- end of container div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is nice hint, but has one problem. If content.php need some js and css, then in that case, i will be forced to write '<head>' in that and again same issue will come.

Comment: Most of the time you are going to have the same CSS and JS linked on all pages, so why not just add them in head.php?

Comment: @user811602 better now?

Comment: @misterManSam, if i neglect caching, every extra file will be overburden to server and bandwidth

Comment: @pc-shooter, i guess u r right. It seems that in web-coding, every redundancy cannot be removed. Neither we can avoid every coupling.

Answer (score 3):

php is rendering html and if you have in both files header of course it will be printed twice

you should separate in includes but don't write in both files  tag

example

```
<header>
<?php
    // this file should not include <head> taf
    include ($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/page/common/header.php);
?>
</header>
BODY
<header>
<?php
    include ($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/page/common/foot.php);
?>
</header>
```

include will bring content from `head.php` and `foot.php` and will put in `index.php` file

Comment: thx. This is really a modular way. Again same question come. If head.php need head.css and foot.php needs foot.css, then index.php need to include both in its head (which make it tightly coupled). Is there any way i can include css in respective files without adding tag <head>

Comment: yes you can add without head ... but you can add inside main file not inside included files or you can add inside head an footer separate it not issue ENJOY :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution to avoid multiple head tags which also makes it possible to add additional css files:

```
<?php
// head.php
$html = <<< EOF
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
    {$meta}
    <link href="../../css/headermenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    {$additional_style}
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="home">Home<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    {$mainbody}
    {$footer}
    {$javascript}
  </body>
  </html>
EOF;
?>

<?php
// page1.php

$title = 'some title';
$meta = '';
$additional_style = '';
$mainbody = 'your body';
$footer = '';
$javascript = '';

include_once("head.php");
echo $html;
?>

<?php
// page2.php

$title = 'some other title';
$meta = '';
$additional_style = '<link href="../../css/page2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>';
$mainbody = 'your body';
$footer = '';
$javascript = '';

include_once("head.php");
echo $html;
?>
```

It also allows for multiple levels of inheritance (for example, you could define the same footer for a couple of pages). This principle can also be used without EOF, but I think that it looks nicer this way.

The main downside is that you will get a warning if you do not set all the variables of head.php in the pages including it.

Comment: thx for solution. I doubt that this is standard, but as an alternate, it is really cool solution with complete decoupling and without any redundancy.